# Sampling from guassian distribution for odometry based motion?

Tags: mobile-robot, odometry, probability

I am trying to generate an odometry based motion model as described in the [lectures](http://ais.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/ss18/robotics/slides/06-motion-models.pdf). I have implemented a C++ version of the code. The issue I am having is that when I try to simulate successive motion using odometry commands the uncertainty in the pose is not increasing. It almost remains the same as the robot moves.

Here is the sampling function

```
double MotionModels::sample_normal_distribution_gaussian(float mean, float standard_deviation) {

   auto lower=-(mean+3*standard_deviation);
   auto upper =mean+3*standard_deviation;
    std::normal_distribution<double> distribution(mean,standard_deviation);
    double temp= distribution(generator);
    while(1){
        if(temp>(lower) && temp<(upper))
            break;
        else
            temp= distribution(generator);
    }

    return temp;

}
```

Here is the motion model :

```
Pose MotionModels::MM_Odometry(Pose &p, Odometry &u, NoiseParams &np) {

    Odometry u_n;
    u_n.delta_rot1 = u.delta_rot1 + sample_normal_distribution_gaussian(0,(np.a1*abs(u.delta_rot1)) + (np.a2*u.delta_trans));
    u_n.delta_trans= u.delta_trans + sample_normal_distribution_gaussian(0,np.a3*u.delta_trans + np.a4*(abs(u.delta_rot1)+abs(u.delta_rot2)));
    u_n.delta_rot2 = u.delta_rot2 + sample_normal_distribution_gaussian(0,np.a1*abs(u.delta_rot2)+np.a2*u.delta_trans);

    Pose out;
    out.x       = p.x + u_n.delta_trans*cos(p.theta+u_n.delta_rot1);
    out.y       = p.y + u_n.delta_trans*sin(p.theta+u_n.delta_rot1);
    out.theta   = p.theta + u_n.delta_rot1 + u_n.delta_rot2;

    return  out;


}
```

Simulation results with a series of motion are as under
[image]

Expected Results
[image]

Would be highly thankful for any help.

**Update :**
Follwoing  @Petch's suggestion I was able to get the following output. The uncertainty increases as the robot moves away from starting point but when I take a 90 degrees turn the behavior is unexpected .

These are the odometery commands I am using along with paramaters

- u1=[0,0,1]  (rot1, rot2,trans)
- u2=[0,0,1.1]
- u3=[0,0,1.3]
- u4=[0,pi/2,1]
- u5=[0,0,1]

Noise Parameters :
-[alpha1,alpha2,aplha3,alpha4]=[0.1,0.1,0.01,0.01]

[image]

Comment: I don't really know about this but I'm wondering if the line `auto lower=-(mean+3*standard_deviation);` is correct.

Comment: Here I am just checking the sigma bounds for the output value I am constraining it to (-3sigma - 3sigma).

Comment: should it be `mean - 3*standard_deviation`?

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: If i have understood the posting correct, the idea is that the robot follows a predefined trajectory and during the ride the robot's position becomes uncertain which is realized with a random generator which is equal to a gaussian model. The problem is, that somebody has to control the robot which is perhaps a macro. In the macro it's defined that the robot is at timecode 0 at waypoint #0, at timecode1 at waypoint #1 and so on.

Comment: The control is symbolized here by odometry commands "u". So according to the model and as you also mentioned the uncertainty should grow as the robot moves but I havnt been able to produce the behaviour.